# RAILS Check which attribute of a model has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand that to check if a model has changed one can use:

```
instance.changed?
```

Also to check if an attribute has changed:

```
instance.attr_changed?
```

but how can we determine which attribute has changed ? Is there a way we can iterate over all the attributes one by one and somehow determine which one has changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at it quite easily using:

```
instance.changed_attributes
```

or

```
instance.changed
```

First one will give you hash `{"attribute" => "value before change"}`.

Second one returns array of name of attributes that changed: `["name of changed attribute"]`.

Comment: hmm... surprisingly, instance.changed? returns true, while instance.changed does not print anything. Any ideas ?

Comment: This is quite interesting. Maybe you're using some gems that overwrite some of the AR functions?
When you look at docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed you can see implementation of `changed`: `changed_attributes.present?`, `changed?`: `changed_attributes.keys` and `changed_attributes`: `@changed_attributes ||= ...`. Therefore - it's not really possible **UNLESS** you're somehow change behaviour of AR.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was overridden. Thanks!